Calculating spatial intersection for multipe large polygon datasets
I have a set of vector layers in R, and I want to keep only those polygons in each layer that intersect across all layers. In other words, a polygon should only be kept if it intersects with a polygon in every other layer. I have 8 layers, and each .gpkg file is about 33 MB.
The following code works fine when applied to a small subset of the layers, but when I try to process the entire dataset, it has been running for more than 2 days now without completing.
Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing the slowdown or how I could increase the speed of the calculation?
# Function to check if a polygon intersects with all other layers
check_intersection_all_layers <- function(polygon, other_layers) {
  for (other_layer in other_layers) {
    intersection <- st_intersects(polygon, other_layer, sparse = FALSE)
    if (!any(intersection)) {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

# Function to filter a layer, keeping only polygons that intersect with at least one polygon in all  other layers
filter_layer_by_intersections <- function(layer, other_layers) {
  keep_indices <- sapply(1:nrow(layer), function(i) {
    check_intersection_all_layers(layer[i, ], other_layers)
  })
  filtered_layer <- layer[keep_indices, ]
  return(filtered_layer)
}

# Apply the filtering to all layers
filtered_layers_list <- lapply(1:length(filtered_polygons_class2_3), function(i) {
  current_layer <- filtered_polygons_class2_3[[i]]
  other_layers <- filtered_polygons_class2_3[-i]
  filter_layer_by_intersections(current_layer, other_layers)
})


You could try collecting all your sf layers in a single spatial dataframe (if you don't have already) and sf_intersection(your_spatial_dataframe) in one go as explained here.

Thanks for the suggestion. But if I have them in one Single dataframe, how can i check if the polygon is persistant in each Layer? I guess if they are in one dataframe, i can only check for one intersection ?

see this answer: sf_intersection on a dataframe will create a colum n.overlaps which you can use to filter for n.overlaps == number_of_layers

Ah Great thanks! And last question, is it possible to Keep the Origin of the Layer? So that I can make them back into Single, Filtered Layers again?

In cases like this, I find processing the data in smaller chunks helps speed things up. Also, if you data are not projected, this adds a lot of overhead to some R functions such as st_intersection(). For instance, the for() loop that subsets the gpkg files in this reprex took ~10 mins just for the first two iterations using WGS84/EPGS:4326 data, whereas the WGS84 Pseudo Mercator/EPGS:3857 equivalent took < 3 mins for all four iterations.
This workflow assumes your data are not projected, hence the inclusion of the org_crs and prj_crs variables. If your data are already projected, set both to be the same as your actual data, or remove all instances of st_transform(). Other modifications you may need to do:

To load your gpkg files in chunks, a WKT string is used. The xmins, xmaxs, ymin, and ymax variables will create n WKT strings/iterations. Following the same logic, modify these to match the extent of your actual data e.g. xmins and xmaxs need to represent n divisions of your min and max longitude, and ymin and ymax need to be just the min and max latitude of your data (or the min/max latitude of the relevant CRS bounding extent).
Because some polygons might be split into parts, add a unique id (poly_id) to your gpkg files before running the for() loop (see the code used to create the sample data for how to do this). This column is needed to recombine any contiguous and/or non-contiguous split polygons. To add this column, st_read() your gpkg files into R, add the necessary column, then st_write() them back to your working directory.
Related to point 2, to ensure a single row for each polygon/multipolygon, summarise() is used. If you have an area column, you will need to recalculate it at the end.
If your data are not projected, you may get an error containing something similar to ! Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 1 crosses edge 4. If so, run sf_use_s2(FALSE) and start everything again.
Take note of the code comments, and the suppressWarnings({}) and suppressMessages({}) in particular. These are added to stop your console being overloaded. Remove them if you want to see the output. The comments are not exhaustive but they cover most key points. This code works for the sample data used but may not for your actual data. Comment below if you encounter an issue.

Step 1: Load packages and create some sample gpkg files approximately the same size as your actual data
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Define variables representing the CRS of your original data
org_crs <- 4326
# Define variable to project data e.g. WGS84 Pseudo Mercator/EPSG:3857
prj_crs <- 3857

# Skip the following if you already have gpkg files
set.seed(42)
x <- 170
y <- 85
cellsize <- .7

for(i in 1:7) {
  
  tmp <- st_bbox(c(xmin = x * -1, xmax = x, ymin = y * -1, ymax = y), crs = org_crs) %>%
    st_make_grid(cellsize = cellsize, square = FALSE) %>%
    st_as_sf() %>%
    mutate(poly_id = 1:n(), # IMPORTANT
           var = runif(n(), 0, 1))
  
  if (file.exists(paste0("data/sf_poly", i, ".gpkg"))) {
    
    file.remove(paste0("data/sf_poly", i, ".gpkg"))
    
  }
  
  st_write(tmp, paste0("data/sf_poly", i, ".gpkg"))
  
  x <- x - 5
  y <- y - 5
  cellsize <- cellsize - 0.03125
  
  rm(tmp)
  
}

# Create sf_poly8 in RAM and subset to replicate  sf with non-contiguous polygons
sf_poly8 <- st_bbox(c(xmin = x * -1, xmax = x, ymin = y * -1, ymax = y),
               crs = org_crs) %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = cellsize, square = FALSE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(poly_id = 1:n(), # IMPORTANT
         var = runif(n(), 0, 1))

# Create sf to subset sf_poly8
sf_subset <- st_bbox(c(xmin = x * -1, xmax = x, ymin = y * -1, ymax = y),
                     crs = org_crs) %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 10, square = FALSE) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Filter the data frame based on the sampled rows
sf_subset <- sf_subset[sample(seq_len(nrow(sf_subset)), size = 50), ]

# Subset sf_poly8 and write to directory
sf_poly8 <- sf_poly8 %>%
  mutate(tmp = as.character(st_intersects(., sf_subset))) %>%
  filter(tmp != "integer(0)") %>%
  select(-tmp)

file.remove("data/sf_poly8.gpkg")

st_write(sf_poly8, "data/sf_poly8.gpkg")

rm(sf_poly8)

Step2: Import gpkg files in n chunks, and subset to extent of where all layers overlap
# List all gpkg files in folder named "data" in your working directory
# You can either copy relevant gpkg files into a "data" folder you create in your
# working directory, or modify to point to the location of the gpkg files
gpkg_files <- list.files("data", pattern = ".gpkg$", full.names = TRUE)

# Define the bounding box coordinates (currently WGS84, edit to match your data)
xmins <- c(-180, -90, 0, 90)
#xmin <- -90
xmaxs <- c(-90, 0, 90, 180)
#xmax <- -0
ymin <- -90
ymax <- 90
# Important: run iter before running for() each time
iter <- 0

# Iterate over bounding box vectors to read subsetted gpkg
for(i in 1:length(xmins)) {
  
  # Create a WKT bbox to subset sf objects
  bbox_wkt <- sprintf("POLYGON((%f %f, %f %f, %f %f, %f %f, %f %f))",
                      xmins[i], ymin, xmins[i], ymax, xmaxs[i],
                      ymax, xmaxs[i], ymin, xmins[i], ymin)
  
  # Subset gpkg files from directory, project to prj_crs
  invisible(
    capture.output({
      suppressMessages({
        suppressWarnings({
          lapply(seq_along(gpkg_files), function(i) {
            sf_obj <- st_read(gpkg_files[i], wkt_filter = bbox_wkt) %>%
              st_transform(prj_crs) %>%
              st_set_geometry("geometry")
            
            # Add projected sf to global environment
            assign(paste0("sf_poly", i), sf_obj, envir = .GlobalEnv)
            
          })
        })
      })
    })
  )
  
  # Use summarise() to create simplifed version of sf_poly* objects
  sf_list <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^sf_poly")), summarise)
  
  # Combine all simplified sf_poly* objects, filter to only where all overlap
  # Note suppressed warning
  sf_all <- suppressWarnings({ 
    
    bind_rows(sf_list) %>%
      st_intersection() %>%
      filter(n.overlaps == 8) %>%
      st_cast("POLYGON")
    
  })
  
  # Set counter for each iteration
  iter <- iter + 1
  
  # Create a list of sf_poly* objects
  sf_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^sf_poly"))
  
  # Subset each sf_poly* object using sf_all and st_intersection(), output results
  # Note suppressed warning
  invisible(suppressWarnings({ 
    
    lapply(seq_along(sf_list), function(i) {
      subset_sf <- st_intersection(sf_list[[i]], sf_all) # %>%
      
      assign(paste0("sf", i, "_iter", iter), subset_sf, envir = .GlobalEnv)
      
    })
  }))
}

Step 3: Clean up any artifacts created by previous step and combine sf objects
In some cases st_intersection() creates point and linestring features in the output. These will be removed using filter(). Similarly, some geometrycollection features may also be present, and these are dealt with at the same time as combining contiguous and non-contiguous polygons using st_collection_extract(), summarise(), and st_union().
# List all subsetted sf objects starting with "sf" followed by digit
sf_subs <- mget(ls(pattern = "^sf[0-9]+"))

# Create function to combine each sf* group
comb_grp <- function(grp, sf_subs) {

  # Combine objects and remove duplicate rows
  combined_sf <- bind_rows(sf_subs[grep(paste0("^", grp), names(sf_subs))]) %>%
    distinct()
  
  return(combined_sf)
  
}

# Return unique sf groups
grp_prefix <- unique(substring(names(sf_subs), 1, 3))

# Apply comb_grp to each sf group, save result
comb_sf_list <- lapply(grp_prefix, function(grp) comb_grp(grp, sf_subs))

# Clean up comb_sf_list objects and add each one to global environment
invisible(lapply(seq_along(comb_sf_list), function(i) {
  
  suppressWarnings({
    x <- comb_sf_list[[i]] %>%
    filter(!st_geometry_type(.) %in% c("POINT", "LINESTRING")) %>%
    mutate(tmp = n(), .by = poly_id) %>%
    filter(tmp == 1) %>%
    bind_rows(
      comb_sf_list[[i]] %>%
        mutate(tmp = n(), .by = poly_id) %>%
        filter(tmp > 1 | st_geometry_type(.) == "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION") %>%
        st_collection_extract() %>%
        summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), .by = c(poly_id))) %>%
    select(-tmp) %>%
    st_transform(org_crs)
    
    })
  
  assign(paste0("combined_", grp_prefix[i]), x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
}))

Examining the result of one combined sf, note the NULL/NA values in the last n rows. These are the features that were either split polygons (now multipolygons), or were a geometrycollection. I like to leave these columns in as it keeps track of what happened during processing. Delete the n.overlaps and origins columns if not needed
head(data.frame(combined_sf1))
#   poly_id        var n.overlaps                origins                       geometry
# 1   21743 0.07686934          8 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 POLYGON ((-116.45 -50.04144...
# 2   21744 0.87413973          8 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 POLYGON ((-116.8 -49.43522,...
# 3   21745 0.31808315          8 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 POLYGON ((-116.8 -48.22279,...
# 4   21746 0.86243617          8 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 POLYGON ((-116.8 -47.01035,...
# 5   21747 0.22632662          8 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 POLYGON ((-116.8 -45.79792,...
# 6   21748 0.58366504          8 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 POLYGON ((-116.1 -44.58548,...

tail(data.frame(combined_sf1))
#       poly_id       var n.overlaps origins                       geometry
# 11109  105013 0.5915658         NA    NULL POLYGON ((89.7 46.75133, 90...
# 11110  105014 0.4889846         NA    NULL POLYGON ((89.7 47.96377, 89...
# 11111  105015 0.2676258         NA    NULL POLYGON ((89.7 49.1762, 90....
# 11112  105016 0.9142720         NA    NULL POLYGON ((89.7 50.27855, 89...
# 11113   85832 0.3937237         NA    NULL POLYGON ((42.1 40.68915, 42...
# 11114   95144 0.3188072         NA    NULL POLYGON ((65.55 48.16584, 6...

